# Closed form representation of recurrence relation 4

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

I want to find a closed form of the following recurrence relation:

$$
a_0=0; \\     
a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}0, & \exists k\in \mathbb{N}_0: n=\frac12 k(k+1); \\
         a_n+1, & \nexists k \in \mathbb{N}_0:n=\frac12 k(k+1). \end{cases}
$$

(In particular, this recurrence relation describes the sequence
$$
(0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,\ldots)
$$
.)

I was not successful in finding an adequate generating function as normal.
How can I proceed?

Comment: I think you intended $a_n=a_{n-1}+1$ when $n$ is not a triangular number.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales You're correct! I'll edit my post.

Comment: Look at the Mathematica section of https://oeis.org/A002262

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Could you elaborate on it further? I'm not sure about how to decipher that entry...

Comment: I tried to decipher it but must have done it wrong, because it is not producing the right numbers. Perhaps someone who knows how to code in Mathematica can help.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the Mathematica results from https://oeis.org/A002262, if we define

$$ m(k)=\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8k-7}-1}{2}\right\rfloor\quad\text{ for }k\ge1 $$

then

$$ a_k= k-m(k+1)\cdot\frac{m(k+1)+1}{2}$$

This produces the sequence

$$ (0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,\ldots) $$